# What is the best way to distribute SSL certificates to Nginx servers in Google startup scripts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'd like to spin up nginx servers on demand that support HTTPS. I'm using the Google startup scripts, and see that I can set metadata using the metadata server. However, Is it kosher to be putting private SSL certificates in project settings in the startup scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Instance metadata is only accessible through instance itself. As such, you can use the metadata server to store your SSL certificate. You can go through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata) to get better understanding of Metadata Server.

You can run a startup script from your local machine as well however, you can  only pass it through gcloud and has a limit of 32768 bytes. More information on startup scripts can be found on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript?hl=en#use_a_local_startup_script).